# Calculating the URI of folders or files in devcontainer on a remote host - Need guidance

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm looking to get some guidance on calculating the URI of folders or files in a devcontainer on a remote Linux machine.

Every morning, I have to go through the following steps to start my development process:

1. Open the devcontainer's folder via VSCode on the remote host.
2. Execute "Reopen in Container" from the command palette.

I'm eager to combine these two steps into one.

I already know how to open VSCode directly on remote machines using a single command, as well as how to open the container on my local machine directly.

For the former, I use the `--folder-uri` and `ssh-remote` options, as shown below:

```
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+<ssh hostname>/home/username/work
```

For the latter, I have been calculating the `--folder-uri` using a slightly complicated procedure, which has been discussed extensively in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2133).

However, I'm unsure how to open VSCode in a Docker container on my remote machine using a single command. I believe there must be a method to calculate the URI of folders or files.

I would greatly appreciate help from someone who is familiar with this problem. Thank you in advance!

I have invastegated the issues in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues.

I have read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/ssh. However, I would like to use docker cli on the remote host. Setting up a docker context on the local machine and talking to the Docker Daemon on the remote machine didn't work for me.